Reputation "lost" but not showing in reputation timeline - bug?
This user apparently lost some reputation points and now the reputation is stuck at "1".  On checking the reputation graph, OP peaked at 295 points and then "lost" 93 points. So, total reputation should be 202 but the reputation is showing "1". I am aware that the user had some of his answer deleted but the reputation shouldn't plunge to 1.



What was this reputation change and why it isn't showing in the timeline? And why the total reputation is stuck at 1?

Reported in Space SE as well: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/reputation-graph-shows-upwards-plot-but-the-value-is-stuck-at-1-bug

This appears to be the result of a system-enforced penalty. In accordance with site policy mods are not at liberty to discuss specifics about specific users in public.

Hmm, that seems fair. Although, I had the impression that users serving penalty has their reputation stuck at 1 and showing no medals. For this user, the reputation was 1, but the medals were showing. So, I did not consider the penalty part at all.
