How to flag issues with questions?
It seems difficult to flag questions for fix here - why is this so difficult? Many recent questions have broken images so I have flagged that but these answers have been been removed.
Broken image (as it appears on my (jenny.essex) browser):

Link to original post
Edit: image with "broken link" was copied and inserted by BuckThorn from that submitted by the post author at imgur.
Edit: for reference, this part of the question was locked for a month so conversations continued under comments.

It is "difficult" because your flags about "broken" illustrations are unsubstantiated and declined as such. It appears that you might experience technical difficulties on your side. As for the "broken image example" here — please see Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur has ended - migration complete! Use i.sstatic.net image uploader, not direct links to Imgur.

Why is it that because 1 person doesn't have issues with things that they are unsubstantiated?

In addition, had you looked at the image you would have seen that the broken bit is referring to i.sstatic.net, not imgur

What "broken bit"? The diagram from https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185526 renders for me just fine both in Chromium- and Firefox-based desktop browsers. Yours here doesn't because it's an Imgur page, not even a hotlinked image.

@andselisk https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185524/how-to-name-these-compounds had bare url

And if OP took my advice to learn, she could fix it herself, even if it was a waste of time. Only flag appropriate there were VLQ or close as homework.

Sadly, as flagged, the image at chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185526 does not render for me in Chromium-, Edge- and Firefox-based desktop browsers. Something has broken but nothing has changed recently at my end.

Sadly, you now got only 1 rep. like you were banned, but I don't see the notice on your account. Looks like more pressing issue than if some photo on deleted post works for you or not.

I don't understand the point of this question. As andselisk explained, imgur hosting is no longer supported. There is an image button in the edit box that allows addition of images. Drag and drop is possible too.

@Mithoron Ehhm, OK, but the question that OP is trying to attach a screenshot of is not that deleted one. I'm not sure I understand what does it have to do with this issue. Bare URLs and inability of web browser to display an image are two unrelated topics IMO.

If you are facing any technical issue, you can reach out to mother Meta - Meta.SE

@Mithoron See https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/reputation-lost-but-not-showing-in-reputation-timeline-bug and https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/reputation-graph-shows-upwards-plot-but-the-value-is-stuck-at-1-bug

So now that we have established that the image was broken, due to no fault of my own can the restrictions on my account that arose due to admin mistunderstanding be reversed? It seems to me as if something broke and you needed a large number of points to see images and this was present for a while before I mentioned the issue. Fortunately, it now seems to have been corrected. Posting the image at i.sstatic.net when i.sstatic.net images were broken for me did not seem to be useful

Any restrictions that may have been imposed on your account are not likely due to your technical problems posting images.

Agreed, not due to my technical problems but problems at Chemistry SE. As such you should have no problems reverting them.

General information about flagging can be found in the help accompanying this site: Privilege flag posts and What if I see someone doing something bad? and all links within, i.e. Meta Stack Exchange.
Now, that being out of the way, it seems you have no trouble flagging posts, but that you are dissatisfied with how your flags are being handled; or how one specific flag was handled. This is very unfortunate.
Most of the flags raised are handled by the community itself. Some need to be handled by moderators (i.e. custom flags), some might be expedited by them. All people involved in this are here on their own time, they are volunteering for this kind of work.
I am speaking for myself (although my fellow mods hopefully agree); I am treating every flag diligently. I will check whatever the flag says and either take action accordingly, or decline with the appropriate response. There is not the world of reasons available, so I'll use the closest one. Occasionally I'll decline with a custom message, that's usually not necessary though.
I've taken the time to review your flagging history and I've identified the post in question. I fully support the decision on that flag. I'm not going to disclose any further details though. If you need to discuss this topic further, please comment on this post and I'll open a chat that allows us to talk privately.
In general I am quite liberal at handling flags. I will usually mark them helpful even when there is little a moderator can do to mitigate the issue.
Many issues on this site are better addressed through a constructive comment rather than a flag for the attention of moderators. If you disagree with an edit - like I said previously - you can @-notify the editor via the comments section. If an edit isn't deliberately introducing errors, defacing the post or is otherwise destructive, a flag is probably not the wisest choice. The reason for this is that moderators rule on the technical issues of the Code of Conduct. So if it isn't a violation of that, we'll decline. If there is the possibility of a technical issue it is better to post on meta; we cannot escalate flags, but we can escalate meta posts.
Please accept that if moderators cannot understand the flag raised, or cannot see the issue you raised, the flag needs to be declined.
I truly hope you'll have a better experience on this site in the future.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
